# Using tablename as variable in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a reporting services project where I'm tasked to show data from different tables in a database depending on which "start date" the user choose in a parameter.

If the user chooses the "start date" to be "01-01-2016" then the table name in the dataset query should be "userdata_2016" and "userdata_2017" if the "start date" is set to 01-01-2017.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean in the tablix or whatever you are using to show it? The dataset will be one, that is why it is parametrized. Otherwise you would have 10 datasets with fixed values for the date and you would not need a parameter. That is why parameters are there.

Comment: I have parametrized my start date in my where clause in the dataset query. But having problems doing the same with the table name.

Comment: Why do you have different tables for different years of the same information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange that the tables are separated out by year and not combined into one table unless the data is different in each table. Union all is one approach, but if the data is different or you don't want to load all data from all of the tables you can use the **IF...ELSE** statement to contain each query.

**As an example:**

```
IF YEAR(@startDate) = 2016
    SELECT * FROM userdata_2016;
IF YEAR(@startDate) = 2017
    SELECT * FROM userdata_2017;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM blah;
```

The else statement isn't needed but I put it in for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: I have not made the database design, but maybe because of performance issues. Each table contains +35 million rows. The If/else method works perfect and faster than UNION ALL. I will use this method. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table valued function that unions all years tables, passing `@start_date` as variable:

```
SELECT * FROM userdata_2016 WHERE Year(@start_date) = 2016

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM userdata_2017 WHERE Year(@start_date) = 2017
```

Another option would be to use a `stored procedure`:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM userdata_' + CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS  nvarchar(4))

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: Use `sp_executesql` and pass parameters as such when you are dealing with dynamic queries.

Comment: @Pred while I wholeheartedly agree you can't use a parameterized query here because the part that changes is the table being selected from. And you can't do that with a parameter.

Comment: You will have parameters: DateFrom and DateTo (or whatever their name are). Table name cannot be parameterized, that is right, for that, I highly suggest to use `QUOTENAME`